# What is the point of using dynamic import in Python?

Tags: python, architecture, software-design

Let's assume there are a bunch of classes and based on incoming a parameter the class needs to be detected and its handle method needs to be invoked.

Possible classes

```py
class A:
    def handle(self):
       print('handle method of A class is invoking')

class B:
    def handle(self):
       print('handle method of B class is invoking')

class C:
    def handle(self):
       print('handle method of C class is invoking')

class D:
    def handle(self):
       print('handle method of D class is invoking')

class E:
    def handle(self):
       print('handle method of E class is invoking')
```

So do you recommend mapping the classes like the following?

```py
class_mapping = {
    'a': A,
    'b': B,
    'c': C,
    'd': D,
    'e': E,
}

class Handler:
   def __init__(self, param):
      klass = class_mapping[param]
      instance = klass()
      instance.handle()
```

Or mapping the classes path and import dynamically? Why?

```py
class_path_mapping = {
    'a': "folder_name.A",
    'b': "folder_name.B",
    'c': "folder_name.C",
    'd': "folder_name.D",
    'e': "folder_name.E",
}

class DynamicImportHandler:
   def __init__(self, param):
      klass = importlib.import_module(class_path_mapping[param])
      instance = klass()
      instance.handle()
```

Comment: From the examples in your questions, it seems that `Handler` and `DynamicImportHandler` do not need to be classes - they don't do anything except initialise another class. You could write a function that creates and returns an instance of one of these classes (following your first approach, as it's simpler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to follow the usual rules:

1. If the set of python modules to be loaded is known in advance, import them. A well-written module should not have any side effects at import time, that includes an excessive CPU or I/O load. In other words, import should be a cheap operation.
2. Leave the dynamic loading for cases where the modules to be loaded are not known in advance, like a plug-in system.

If you think your case does not fit into the general rules, please provide more information.

The first case with the `class_mapping` dict would be:

```
handler = class_mapping[param] # create an instance
```

and then:

```
handler.handle() # invoke the method
```